# How to say a negative number in Mandarin?

Tags: translation

There are plenty of posts for rules on numbers, but I can't seem to figure out how one would say, for example, -5 (negative five). I know that negative number is 负数, so would it just be 负五？

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Negative numbers are simply read `负xxx`, for example:

> -5 负五
>
> -1234.5 负一千二百三十四点五
>
> (-3) x 5 = -15 负三乘以五等于负十五
>
> 2^(-3) 二的负三次方

When applied to certain domain, there might be domain specific way to read it. For example for temperature, it's more common to read it as 零下 (literally 'below zero'):

> -10°C 零下十（摄氏）度

Reading as `负十度` is also correct, just less common.

Reference:

[人教版小学四年级数学 第七单元 生活中的负数](http://beike.dangzhi.com/view/59ngmj)